# Python - Take an int variable and times it by a float?

Tags: python

As a learning project, I'm attempting to write a small game to simply get familiar with the Python language as well as build my programming skills. Being somewhat of a gamer, I always seem to want to add additional code to the game to make it more playable and therefore enjoyable. Right now I'm stuck on stupid and hope this is fairly easy to solve by the more familiar:

**Python 3.8.8**

I have an **int** that has been randomly selected and added it to a variable:

```
if act_trl_cls == trl_cls[0]:
    trl_atk_pwr = random.randint(7.0, 10.0)
```

What I'm looking to do is create a **float** (for percentage purposes) add it to a variable:

```
if act_trl_cls == trl_cls[0]:

    trl_cls_wpn_ran = random.uniform(0.01, 0.05)
    trl_cls_wpn_dmg = "{:.2f}".format(trl_cls_wpn_ran) # converts to two decimal points
```

... and then multiply them to get a percentage, much like we do with tipping.

Example:

Bill Total: **$53.56**

$53.56 * .20 = $10.71

$53.56 + $10.71 = $64.27

Total: **$64.27**

My question is how do we represent this in Python? Everytime I attempt:

```
if fight_confirmation == "Y" or fight_confirmation == "y":
    total = trl_atk_pwr * trl_cls_wpn_dmg
```

... I end up with:

```
0.030.030.030.030.030.030.030.03
```

... or some other variation depending on the random **int** and **float** chosen by the **random** function and respective method rather than the return value of the multiplied values assigned to each variable. Obviously this is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: `"{:.2f}".format(0.03)` returns a `str`, not a `float`. In Python, you can 'multiply' `str` by `int`, which creates a string duplicated `n` times. That is why you end up with a `str`: `"0.030.030.030.030.030.030.030.03"` which is the string `"0.03"` duplicated `trl_atk_pwr` times.

Comment: Jeez, this is what type() is used for! I should have known. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert it to float before multiplication like below .

```
if fight_confirmation == "Y" or fight_confirmation == "y":
    total = float(trl_atk_pwr) * float(trl_cls_wpn_dmg)
```

You are getting this because now you are getting trl_cls_wpn_dmg  as a string and it will do concatenation when you are multiplying it by a number.